# How can i display the function of short-code in option tree framework meta box?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

I having Trouble while calling the shortcode ultimate short-code

```
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'itineary', true);
```

The above code display the content as plain text but i have to use

```
[su_button icon="icon: bullhorn"]Button text[/su_button]
```

this short-code to add a button but it show also in plain text...

Hoping for a solution!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
echo do_shortcode( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'itineary', true ) );
```

Comment: Thanks it works and i found in https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-optiontree-allow-shortcodes-in-textarea?replies=5

Noway , Thank You @JayDeep